# How can I separate the closing price to only analyze the hundredths

Tags: pine-script

I need to identify in the closing price if it has hundredths such as $ 12.001, for which I only want to know when the price has .001-.009 if the condition is met, then I will analyze the volume related to those cases.

any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OBJx.jpg)
example: I need the yellow ones

thanks

Comment: So, are you asking how to separate the decimal part from the closing price?

Comment: yes, and then count the number of digits, if number of digits> 2 then true

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get the decimal part, you can just subtract the integer part from the whole number. After that, since you want to know if # of digits > 2, multiply the number by 100. If the new decimal part is zero, you know that # of digits are <= 2.

This should do. `isMoreThanTwoDigit` will be true, when # of digits are > 2 and false otherwise.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

float price = close
float dec = price - int(price)
float price2 = dec * 100
float dec2 = price2 - int(price2)
bool isMoreThanTwoDigit = dec2 == 0 ? false : true
plot(isMoreThanTwoDigit ? 1 : 0, color = color.red)
```

Here are some examples where it is false ( < 2 digits ):

Close: 10.740000
[image]

Close: 6.200000
[image]

Close: 6.040000
[image]

Close: 3.000000
[image]

Comment: thanks, is what I needed to complete my script